# Solr suggest - How to define solr suggest as case insensitive

Tags: solr, autocomplete

My suggest (spellchecker) is returning case sensitive answers.
(I use it to autocomplete - dog and Dog return different phrases)\

my suggest is defined as follows - 
in solrconfig -

```
 <searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
<lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
    <str name="field">suggest</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
    <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <!--<str name="sourceLocation">american-english</str>-->
</lst>
</searchComponent>
<requestHandler class="org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler" name="/suggest">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">suggest</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
        <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

in schema

```
<field name="suggest" type="phrase_suggest" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

and

```
<copyField source="Name" dest="suggest"/>
```

and

```
<fieldtype name="phrase_suggest" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}]*[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}\_]+:)|([^\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Cs}])+"
            replacement=" " replace="all"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldtype>
```

Comment: did you rebuild the index after doing this? I can't see a problem by looking at it

Comment: Thanks. By rebuild do you mean restart solr, full import and commit? Yes. Did that.

Comment: if it's not working it means either yor tokens or your querty are not being lowercased. can you check them and see if the lowerCaseFilterFactory is working?

Comment: When I query all the results are definitely not lower cased. Maybe this is the problem. How do I fix that?

Comment: No you donøt have to look at the results, they are stored as they are passed, but it does not mean that the tokens are not lowercase. can you debug your query and send how it get parsed?

Comment: This is a suggest request (based of spellchecker). debug doenst seem to work (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/vault/suggest?q=c&wt=xml&indent=true&debugQuery=true)

Comment: Then I suggest you split your analyzer into "query" and "index" and start stripping out the unnecessary parts until you find the issue. Start only with the LowerCaseFilterFactory (and obvioulsy your KeywordTokenizerFactory) and remove all other filters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the order of filter factories which are added into the `fieldType`. Also, place `LowerCaseFilterFactory` at the top of the list.

Shishir

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to add the field type to the search component declaration in solrconfig.xml
In this case "phrase_suggestion" but match to whatever fieldtype you have created in schema.xml that has the lowercasefilterfactory declared.

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
        <str name="field">suggest</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
        <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

        <!-- THIS IS THE LINE TO ADD -->
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">phrase_suggest</str>

    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the correct configparamter is "queryAnalyzerFieldType" and is has to go outside the list element, like so:

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SpellCheckComponent" name="suggest">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">suggest</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.tst.TSTLookup</str>
        <str name="field">suggest</str>  <!-- the indexed field to derive suggestions from -->
        <float name="threshold">0.005</float>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>

    </lst>
    <!-- Make it case-insensitive -->
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
</searchComponent>
```

This works for spelling correction as well as suggestions.