# Solr Suggester - case insensitive

Tags: java, solr, search-suggestion

I am trying to work on an autocomplete feature on Solr and the way I found how to do it, is to use  [Solr Suggester](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Suggester). However, it does not work as expected. If someone invokes `http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=a` while the index has a field that starts with `Apple` it will not come out. I have request with `suggest.q=A` (with an upper case).

Is there a way to make Solr Suggester case-insensitive?

Here are my configurations:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
   <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">autocomp</str>
      <str name="weightField">price</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
   </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Here are relevent parts of the schema:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="autocomp" type="textSuggest" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="title" dest="autocomp"/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out that the issue is with this part of searchComponent configurations:

```
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
```

You have to put the field you are using for analyzing the text. In my case it was:

```
<str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this probably doesn't solve the issue of not returning any results, to achieve case-insensitivity I think you should set the value of the suggestAnalyzerFieldType to textSuggest. See [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/learnthenknow/p/3762801.html). Even the spell check component had [something alike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685979/solr-suggest-how-to-define-solr-suggest-as-case-insensitive) but in an another attribute.